# Given matrix associated to linear transformation find the basis it corresponds to

Tags: matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I know how to find the matrix associated to a linear transformation with respect to two given basis, but how can one find the basis given the matrix?

Let's say we're given a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R_2}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R_2}[x]$, where $T(p(x)) = x\cdot p^{\prime}(x)$

We know that the matrix associated to $T$ in two bases $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ is of the form:
$T_{\beta_1\beta_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 2\\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$

I know that if $\beta_1 = \{q_1, q_2, q_3\}$ then: $\\$ $T(q_1)_{\beta_2} = (1,0,0); \\ T(q_1)_{\beta_2} = (0,1,0); \\ T(q_3)_{\beta_2} = (1,2,0)$

But how can I actually find $\beta_1, \beta_2$?